# JAVA, GUICE Transaction and synchronize when transfer money

Tags: java, transactions, synchronization, guice

I am implementing transferring money from bank account to another bank account. My question is if I have `@Transactional` annotation (from guice) do I have to use synchronize ? Does Transactional ensure that another thread wont hit the resource ?

```
 @Transactional(rollbackOn = RuntimeException.class)
    synchronized public void transfer(@NonNull final Transfer transfer) {        
        withdrawFromOwnerAccount(ownerAccount, transfer.getAmount());
        depositToReceiverAccount(receiverAccount, transfer.getAmount());

    }
```

Comment: Just to clearify, is this a method inside a Singleton? Do you use instance variables in Singletons?

Answer (score -1):

"UnitOfWork is threadsafe and can be cached for multiple uses or injected directly into singletons." [see](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Transactions)

Therefore, my answer is yes.

Btw. Synchronized will only be effective if the threads handle the same object, (Singleton?).

Important is that the underlying dbms can handle transactions in a safe way. I assume a kind of mysql or postgres are used. The framework should make sure that the connection used to do the transaction and database operations is used exclusively in one thread during one transaction. That's a quite simple requirement and handled quite safely in java-servers for 20 years.

Comment: https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/persist/Transactional.html Where is the definition UnitOfWork in @Transanctonal? So your answer is to assume a lot and citing things that are not even in the pertinent docs this is how you handle other people money?

Comment: @efekctive please follow the link

Comment: please read the question and the docs. The unit of work code does NOT use @Transactional. Please leave me alone and research your answers better

Comment: @efekctive "We have so far seen how to create a unit of work that spans a single transaction"